# Symfony 2.3: Remember form inputs while visiting another site

Tags: php, forms, session, symfony

**What I have:**

A form with several different input fields etc. The interesting part is a collection field:

```
$builder->add( 'publicationAuthors', 'collection', array (
            'type' => new AuthorPublicationType(),
            'allow_add' => true,
            'allow_delete' => true,
            'by_reference' => false,
            'label' => 'Autoren' 
));
```

This collection refers to another FormType, including only an entity field and an order id:

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options) {
    $builder->add( 'author', 'entity', array (
            'class' => 'indPubBundle:Author',
            'multiple' => false,
            'label' => 'Autor',
            'query_builder' => function (EntityRepository $er) {
                return $er->createQueryBuilder( 'a' )
                    ->orderBy( 'a.author_surname', 'ASC' );
            } 
    $builder->add( 'order_id', 'hidden');
    ));
}
```

Via JS I am able to add new collection form fields to my form so the user can then choose several of the authors and order them.

**What I need:**

So far, the user can only choose existing authors due to the entity field. I want to enhance the form such that the user is also able to create new authors and use these in the form. I thought of adding a button which redirects the user to a new form where he can create a new author. Then, after submitting that form, the user should be redirected back to the original form and continue to fill it out.

The main problem here is, that I want to remember the user's previous inputs to the original form so that he doesn't need to start all over. Is there a way to remember these inputs while the user is using the author creation form?

I thought of remembering the data in the session, but there is a problem with that: If the user would open a new tab, he might overwrite the old form inputs, since the session ID is the same for both tabs.

Comment: You can do it with session, just save it in an array, and if the session already exists, just add your new entity in the array instead of creating new session.

Comment: Okay, but how do I distinguish between the different entries afterwards?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay I found a solution that is satisfying for me.
Basically, I take the whole form data, serialize it and remember that in a hidden form field.
Because the serialize function returns several signs that are not useable in html, I also encode the string with base64.